# List with many structs recognized as having just one member

Tags: c++

In the following program, I pass `data`, which contains many different days, to the function `GetAvgDayVolm()`, the `cout` statement within this function then outputs `1`.

But it should output more than `1` because there are more than one different dates in `data`. It looks `curTime` is changed though the program doesn't go inside the `if` statement at all. Do you see anything wrong?

```
long int GetAvgDayVolm(list<struct DataPoint>* data)
{
    long long int totalVolm = 0;
    long int numOfDays = 1;
    struct DataPoint dp = (*data).front();
    time_t rawTime2 = dp.timeStamp;
    time_t rawTime  = 0;
    struct tm* curTime = gmtime(&rawTime2);

    struct tm* movingTime = new struct tm ();

    for(list<struct DataPoint>::iterator it = (*data).begin(); it != (*data).end(); ++it)
    {
        rawTime = (*it).timeStamp;
        movingTime = gmtime(&rawTime);
        totalVolm += (*it).volm;

        if(curTime->tm_mday != movingTime->tm_mday || 
           curTime->tm_mon  != movingTime->tm_mon || 
           curTime->tm_year != movingTime->tm_year)
        {
            numOfDays = numOfDays + 1;
            curTime = movingTime;
        }
    }

    cout<<numOfDays<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to either copy the data out, or use `gmtime_r` (`gmtime_s` on Windows).  I would do the latter, since it is thread-safe.

Comment: Unrelated: either you do an awful lot of insertions in the middle, splices and the like, or you should probably reconsider the usage of `std::list`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the pointer that is returned from the `gmtime()` function which is basically a communal chunk of memory that every caller using the time functions shares. The way to fix that is to copy the value out (by dereferencing the returned pointer) rather than keeping a copy of the pointer.

In a multithreaded environment you would also need to take further precautions. Either use one of the thread-safe versions (`gmtime_r`/`gmtime_s`) or synchronize access using a mutex (slow).

Also I would consider changing your function parameter from a *pointer* to a *const reference* because it is always assumed to exist and is not modified by the function.

Here is a possible solution for your function:

```
// pass by const reference if possible because
// the list is assumed to exist and is never modified
long int GetAvgDayVolm(const list<DataPoint>& data)
{
    if(data.empty()) // possible crash later without this check
        return 0;

    long long int totalVolm = 0;
    long int numOfDays = 1;
    DataPoint dp = data.front(); // REQUIRES list contains at least one element
    time_t rawTime2 = dp.timeStamp;
    time_t rawTime  = 0;

    // don't use pointer here, dereference the
    // returned value
    std::tm curTime = *gmtime(&rawTime2);

    // no need for pointer here - dereference the
    // return value of gmtime() instead
    std::tm movingTime;

    for(list<DataPoint>::const_iterator it = data.begin(); it != data.end(); ++it)
    {
        rawTime = it->timeStamp;
        movingTime = *gmtime(&rawTime);
        totalVolm += it->volm;

        if(curTime.tm_mday != movingTime.tm_mday ||
           curTime.tm_mon  != movingTime.tm_mon ||
           curTime.tm_year != movingTime.tm_year)
        {
            numOfDays = numOfDays + 1;
            curTime = movingTime;
        }
    }

    cout<<numOfDays<<endl;
    return 0; // is this correct??
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In the gmtime manpage,the NOTES section says:

```
The four functions asctime(), ctime(), gmtime() and localtime() return a pointer to static data and hence are not thread-safe
```

so in your code the curTime and movingTime point to the **same static data area**, you should use gmtime_r instead, or just save the result first.